# Command to verify that desktop is loaded completely

Tags: raspbian, terminal, raspberry-pi-desktop

What is the terminal command that verifies RaspbianOS is loaded completely? Any other command that does not return the value unless the environment is loaded is fine also?

Comment: There is nothing specific to Raspbian Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Unfortunately "OS loaded completely" is too ambiguous a concept to have any real implementation.  You need instead to focus on specifically what it is you need from the OS (online networking, etc), and in what context (see also the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)).  *"The environment is loaded"* -> Environment is a concrete term, although it is per process and so testing for it system wide is non-sensical.  I suspect you mean something else, but again, you will have to be more specific and explicit about exactly what you need to do and why.

Comment: *"verify the desktop is loaded"* -> Use an autostart file to write something to `/tmp`, and then you can test for the existence of that.